# Figma Editing Pain for Carbon Design System

Tags: interface-design, figma, style-guide

I am attempting to leverage the Carbon Design System by IBM in my Figma designs. I cannot seem to affect the colors in any way other than detaching them which ruins the whole structure of the file system. All of the styles appear to be converted to variants. And all the variants are aliased with no way to edit the base hex that these alias are pulling from.

I also have the IBM Carbon Color Figma library published as well. And I edited a style there, thinking that maybe these two files are talking to each other. But no, no changes when updating libraries.

What am I missing? Do I not understand the structure of this file system? Is Carbon not actually intended to adapt for use with other colors?

Comment: A brief look at IBM's website (https://carbondesignsystem.com/designing/) gave me the impression that their Carbon Design System is meant only for people designing for IBM content including their trademarked colors. Not the easiest website to figure out, considering they are selling UI/UX products.